# Nodejs npm mysql2

Tags: node.js

В старом проекте отвалилась работоспособность пакета mysql2. Решил проверить создал новый проект и выполнил следующие команды:

1. npm init
2. npm install mysql --save
3. npm install express --save

Для экспреса всё отлично а вот для mysql2 пишет следующую ошибку первый раз с ней столкнулся:

> Не удалось найти файл объявления модуля "mysql2". "d:/_tmp/tmp/node_modules/mysql2/index.js" имеет неявный тип "any".
>     Try `npm install @types/mysql2` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mysql2';`ts(7016)

Пример моего кода:

```
const db = require("express");
const mysql2 = require("mysql2");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы импортируете mysql2, поэтому загрузите его `npm install mysql2`

Comment: в шаге 2 я это делаю npm install mysql2 --save и пробовал старую версию взять, такое впечатление, либо где-то в кэши засело, либо пакет залит битый в чём сомневаюсь.

Comment: Проверьте `package.json`, установлен ли модуль. Посмотрите в `node_modules`

Comment: На скрине всё видно, он есть в пакетах и установлен. Понижение версии тоже без результатов. Хотя другие пакета пашут на ура именно почему-то не пашет пакет mysql2. Даже такая штука когда создаю абсолютно новый проект и устанавливаю этот пакет то сразу эта ошибка.

Comment: Так у вас проект работает? У меня в рабочем проекте такое же предупреждение. На работу не влияет... Если хотите убрать, то `npm install @types/mysql2`

Comment: Нет проект запускается и висит на запросе к базе данных.То-есть селект из бд не возвращается. Далее должна в логе идти проверка пользователя и роли но её нет она отваливается и вист на бд. Я поэтому и написал, еслиб она просто висела и работала яб стал писать. Я с пониманием дела написал и тут не банально простая проблема забыл пакет или переустановить. Всё простые действия были выполнены, я их перечислил. Пакет упал во всех проектах. Переустановка платформы nodejs не дала результата.

Comment: Ищите проблему в коде скорее. И, кстати, у вас замечено использование промиса в функции запроса. Совет: используйте встроенную обертку в [промис](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper)

Comment: Нашёл проблему на продуктиве поменяли пароль и не сказали. Спасибо вопрос более не актуален. Проверил продуктів на мысль натолкнула что пакет не работает во многих проектах которые коннектятся к продуктивному серверу.